# Cannot load Facebook SDK for JavaScript v 2.4 in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display a like and a share button in side my chrome extension's `popup.html`. So, I have added the sdk code in `facebook-2.4.js` and loaded it in the `head` tag of `popup.html`.
I tried to test Facebook Integration by putting this code in the `body` of my `popup.html`:

```
<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

But, I got this error in chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED 
chrome-extension://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js
```

Here's what I tried:
In the `manifest` I added `https://connect.facebook.net/` as permission. I also tried with the `http` version of the url. It didn't work.

Note: Read the discussion in the `Comments` section before classifying this question as a duplicate of other unrelated questions.

Comment: Are you displaying facebook posts/timeline in your extension's popup? Or the extension adds functionality to an already opened facebook page? Also what's inside `facebook-2.4.js`?

Comment: @wOxxOm I am not displaying Facebook posts/timeline in my extension's popup. I want to display a like and a share button. Extension doesn't add functionality to an already opened Facebook page. `facebook-2.4.js` contains the javascript code which Facebook instructs you to copy during addition and set up of a new js app in developer.facebook.com

Comment: @wOxxOm `facebook-2.4.js` contains the code which you provided in `content.js` file in your answer.

Comment: Okay, try replacing `//` with `https://`

Comment: @wOxxOm Error: Refused to load the script 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88207/discussion-between-manojit-ghosh-and-woxxom).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome extension Content Security Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596026/google-chrome-extension-content-security-policy)

Comment: These two questions are about two separate errors. Merely the fact that debugging the error mentioned in this question led to a Content Security Policy error, does not make this question a duplicate of that question. Comments section should not be used to misguide people.

Comment: `Misguide` is an exaggeration. The solution from that question appears to be perfectly applicable here and the question itself deals with exactly the same problem: loading of facebook API script.

Comment: (that solution is very good actually, because loading the external script directly into a privileged environment of a Chrome extension you're trying to use is reckless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `//` with `https://` in the file `facebook-2.4.js`.