# CSP error in chrome extension even after adding CSP directive in manifest and sandboxing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to display a *Like* and a *Share* button in side my chrome extension's popup.html. I am getting this error:

[image]

In an attempt to correct this error, I did the following:

1. Added `CSP` directive in the manifest
2. Implemented sandboxing as advised [in this
       post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596026/google-chrome-extension-content-security-policy)

But, that made no difference and I am still getting the same error.

**Code:**

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extension Name</title>
    <style>
body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 90%;

      }

      #news {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      }
      table {
      width: 100%;
      }
      table td, td * {
      vertical-align: top;
      }
      a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
    <base target="_blank">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="facebook-2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="news">
        Statement:<br>

        <table id="newstable"></table>
    </div><iframe class="sandbox active" height="200" id="sandboxFrame" name=
    "sandboxFrame" src="sandbox.html" style="" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $.get("http://example.com/feed/", function(data) {
        $(data).find("item").each(function() {
            var e = $(this);
            $("#newstable").append("<tr><td><a href='" +
                e.find("link").text() + "'>" + e.find(
                    "encoded").text().replace("<p>",
                    "").replace(/style.*/,
                    "style='width: 80px; height: 80px; float: left; margin-right: 5px;'/>"
                ) + "</a></td><td><a href='" + e.find(
                    "link").text() + "'>" + e.find(
                    "title").text() + "<br>" + e.find(
                    "description").text().replace(
                    /<p>The post.*/, "").replace(
                    "<p>", "").replace("</p>", "") +
                "</a></td></tr>");
        });
    });
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Extension name"
    },
    "permissions": ["http://example.com/", "http://*.facebook.com/*", "tabs"],
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**facebook-2.4.js:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'APP_ID',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.4'
    });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**sandbox.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="facebook-2.4.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-show-faces="true" data-width=
    "450"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension to apply the new changes in manifest.json.

Comment: I think we should be more focused on finding the real issue.

Comment: That *is* the real issue. Clearly, your `manifest.json` whitelists `https://connect.facebook.com`, but your screenshot shows that it was blocked. That is a sign that you just added the origin to the `content_security_policy` section in the manifest file without reloading the extension. So reload the extension at `chrome://extensions`.

Comment: I just rechecked after reloading, only for your satisfaction, and got the same error. See the screenshot. Source of the error is a statement in facebook-2.4.js.

Comment: If you got exactly the same screenshot, then you didn't really reload the extension. The error message in the log shows the CSP that was being applied, which is clearly different from the one from your manifest file. Keep in mind that reloading the background page, popup or tab is NOT reloading the extension, to reload the extension you have to click on the "Reload (Ctrl + R)" link at `chrome://extension`.

Comment: I closed and reopened the Canary and rechecked and got something new: https://i.imgur.com/Ao6IaUZ.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88257/discussion-between-manojit-ghosh-and-rob-w).